# Magento 2: how to debug pub/static files generation in developer mode?

Tags: magento2, module, payment

I am developing a custom payment module in Magento2. I used http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/ as example to build it.

I need to debug static code generation. Where are generated `pub/static/` files ? What `class/method` works to do it?

I'm going crazy to make this work on a develop server. I dont understand why method-renderer files are not loadng into http://myserver.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/es_AR/MyVendor_MyCustomPayment/js/view/payment/custom-payment.js when it exists in magento project (`pub/static`).

I tried:

1. `php bin/magento module:enable MyVendor_MyCustomPayment --clear-static-content`
2. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. `rm -rf var/di`
4. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
5. `php bin/magento --ansi setup:static-content:deploy es_AR`
6. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
7. Verify file permissions: `(ls -la var/)`
8. `chown -R magento_user:www-data var/ pub/static/`
9. `find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento`

Comment: That's not code generation (which happens in `var/generation`), but static file deployment, which seems to work fine for you. Something else is happening there. Double check file name and make sure [this is correct](https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe/blob/master/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml). I had troubles with such files myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how much it will help you but you can add verbose mode to the static content deploy command, up to three levels.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -v
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -vv
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -vvv
```

It has helped me track down errors in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Good entry point to debug:

- `\Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource::launch`

`var_dump($params)` after `$this->parsePath($path);`

Module key is empty?

- Reason would probably be a problem with `registration.php` and/or `module.xml`